# Python has stopped working

Tags: python, numpy, windows-10

I'm running a Python script on my windows 10 machine. The script reads compressed data files, stored as .tar.gz, processes it, and then reads the next one. In this manner it processes thousands of files.

I run the scipt in a windows10 powershell, and -seemingly randomly- I often get the following error:

[image: python_stopped_working]

Some times this happens after a day, sometimes already after a few minutes.
I select 'Close program' and the script is terminated. Looking into Windows event viewer, I can see the following entry:

> Faulting application name: python.exe, version: 3.6.2150.1013, time
>   stamp: 0x59c1326e Faulting module name: multiarray.cp36-win_amd64.pyd,
>   version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x59c3eeda Exception code: 0xc0000005

Any ideas on how to avoid this error message?

Comment: You should start it in environment where you can see the error (probably some exception)

Comment: Can you post the relevant part of the script?

Comment: I'm logging errors to a .txt file. There are none. Hence I also do not know at which line the script crashes...

Comment: I would suggest running the script in the command prompt or PowerShell. There, you will be able to see where exactly the script runs into issues.

Comment: Could you have different versions of Python installed?

Comment: The script is running in a powershell. No errors reported apart from above servicelog entry. There is only a single version of Python (3.6) installed on my machine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

0xc0000005 means 'memory access violation' error.
The related info seems to indicate this happens when python is processing arrays.

You can try to trouble shoot by adding logs so you can identify the issue.
The problem may be solved by changing related code.

If you are able to replicate the issue consistently and the python code seems correct - it may be a rare case of a bug in python.

Comment: thx. Very helpful. Any ideas on how I can find out where exactly multiarray.cp36-win_amd64.pyd is being used in my script?

Comment: Check if your code is using try except blocks. You can try to print stack trace report so you get some idea which line of your code led to the issue. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html for examples.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but solving the error requires changing the most essential parts of my code, which I'm not able to do. Do you kindly have any other useful suggestions?